# Apple iOS developer license...?

Tags: developer-program

I just got an Apple iOS Developer License for $100.  I thought it would be effective immediately, but apparently it has to be shipped to me?  I'm really confused, how do I activate my license?  Thanks.

Comment: Did you see the part about getting an email in the 3rd item at  https://developer.apple.com/programs/start/standard/  ..?

Comment: I got an email saying that it's processing, but it still hasn't finished processing.  This is what it says:

`
Your purchase is pending.

You've already placed an order on the Apple Online Store for this item, which may take several minutes to process. Once your purchase is complete, you will receive an activation confirmation from Apple Developer Program Support.


iOS Developer Program
Membership for one year.

`

Comment: As you can see, it is not immediate.  Has it been more than the 24 hours they mention on the site?